# scrapy link extractor not allow restrict text

Tags: python, scrapy

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor  
scrapy shell "http://www.google.com/search?q=hello"
x=LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//td[@class="b navend"]',restrict_text='Next').extract_links(response)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'restrict_text'
```

I am trying to get the "Next" URL from google search, I want to limit the extracted links to only "Next" text,I checked [Link-extractors docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html) what should I do to fix this so I can allow certain links with certain text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`restrict_text` was added in Scrapy 1.7.0.

You must be using a lower version of Scrapy, while reading the latest documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> restrict_text (a regular expression (or list of)) – a single regular
>   expression (or list of regular expressions) that the link’s text must
>   match in order to be extracted. If not given (or empty), it will match
>   all links. If a list of regular expressions is given, the link will be
>   extracted if it matches at least one.

Pls read above guide and understand it before you can fix your issue. You need to give a regular expression not a text as your code. Another the way, you can use xpath or css to extract any elements from html result if you like.

I think you can use scrapy shell to test your extract data first. If it's right you can easier to copy them to your code project.

Comment: this is not the issue, I am unable to use it regardless how